SSO in Blazor 8 - no entry in AspNetUserLogins is written
I have a Blazor web app on .NET 8 with Identity Framework. I want to use SSO with Microsoft and therefore I configured:
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
    {
        microsoftOptions.ClientId = builder.Configuration["MicrosoftClientID"];
        microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = builder.Configuration["MicrosoftClientSecret"];
    });

in my program.cs. On the Login page, the Microsoft button appears. When I click it, I get redirected to Microsoft and end up in ExternalLogin OnLoginCallbackAsync().
SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync() delivers the correct information, the user and a provider key.
As far as I understood, this information should be stored in AspNetUserLogins, but this table stays empty. Therefore ExternalLoginSignInAsync returns "failed".
I guess the entry in AspNetUserLogins should be written in Account/PerformExternalLogin  but I am not able to scaffold this or debug it.
Has anyone any Idea on this?
In Blazor on .NET 7, this worked just fine.

The Blazor 8's identity is different than the blazor 7, the blazor 7 is still use the identity's razor page , but the blazor 8 is using the blazor identity which is component.
After I tested inside my-side it works well. The blazor identity will directly use the SignInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync method.
After login in successfully, it will show like below:

After associated, then it will add the data into the AspNetUserLogins.


Thanks, I know this, but I would need it in another way. In my app, the users are not registering themselfs, but they are created by admins. And I want the SSO (with Mircosoft) to be enabled directly, when the user is craeted.
